# "redirect_uri"doesn't work using OAuth2 client

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, client

```
const CLIENT_ID              = '....';
const CLIENT_SECRET          = '';
const REDIRECT_URI           = 'http://localhost/myappli/web/app_dev.php/';
const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'http://example.com/';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT         = 'http://example/index.php5/oauth/access_token';


/**
 * Connexion to API
 *
 * @return response
 */
public function connexionAction()
{
    $client = new Client(self::CLIENT_ID, self::CLIENT_SECRET);

    if (!isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        $authUrl = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(self::AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT, self::REDIRECT_URI);
        return $this->redirect($authUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        $params = array('code' => $_GET['code'], 'redirect_uri' => self::REDIRECT_URI);

        $infosConnexion = $client->getAccessToken(self::TOKEN_ENDPOINT, 'authorization_code', $params);
        $accessToken = $infosConnexion['result']['access_token'];
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        $response = $client->fetch('http://example/index.php5/api/v3/user/infos');
        //var_dump($response);exit;
    }
}
```

This is my code to connect to an other application using oauth2 to get `access_token` in order to using it to connect then to an API.

But the issue is that after authenticating I am not redirected to my application ("`http://localhost/myappli/web/app_dev.php/`").

So how it is possible to be redirected to my application to get the `access_token` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given the same redirect uri in your application settings page? If you specify about your application (type of application like facebook, twitter etc.,) I can help you in better way.

Comment: What do you mean about my application setting page ?

Comment: While you create an application, you may ask to provide your site url and redirect url. Check those urls with what you provided in your script.